# Create a file with a naming convention in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I was wondering if there is a way to create a file, with a fixed naming convention. To be precise, I would like to find out a way to File > New > SQL Migration and if you specify a file name like CreateAwesomeTable.. it generates a file called V1__CreateAwesomeTable.sql

Answer (score 0):

Not currently possible. Please vote for [IDEA-127570](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127570)